# why my relative path always toward root

Tags: html, relative-path

This is my code in `index.html`

```
   <script src="scripts/vendor.js”>
```

And my `index.html` in `localhost/dist/index.html`

My vendors. in `localhost/dist/scripts/vendor.js`

But when I open the html, browser always told me :

```
can’t find localhost/scripts/vendor.js
```

Comment: find <base href="/“>,it made relative not work,delete it and solved

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do `<script src="./scripts/vendor.js”>`

Not sure if this will work but you can try

Comment: why dont u try to make a different folder for scripts outside the html location eg
dist-> html
dist-> scripts
and use <script scr= "../scripts/vendor.js">

either way its good to keep html and js in different locations not a subfolder